# Send register value to RAM assembly lanuguage

Tags: assembly, dos, interrupt

I am making a DOS picture viewer. For the next part I must set it so that it finds the value of each pixel then sends it to a file I'm using `AH=40 INT 21` to send it to the file, but the data must be in the program but I'm using `AH=0D INT 10` to find the color of the pixel and it saves it in a register. I need to make a byte in the file the value of a register. I probally need to do something like DB "reister value". In other words I need to make address 0250 lets say be the value of AL, or send the register value to RAM. Im running in 'AH=0 AL=13 INT 10' 64000 pixels 256 colors

Comment: Yes, you can read the pixels one by one and store them into memory (`mypixel db 0` in you data segment, and `mov [mypixel], al` and the point `ds:dx` at `mypixel`). But since it seems like you're using mode 13h you can just write the pixels directly (the 64000 pixels are located at 0a000:0000).

Comment: I checked 0A000:0000 and I found nothing (Im not that good with Segments btw im writing this in assembly so I cant create the variable my pixel its just the register AL which has the pixel value

Comment: Try posting a minimal code snippet of what you have and where you're having trouble, that would make it a lot easier to make suggestions. Also please be clear on what video mode you're using, is it 13h 320x200 256 color or is it text mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to process anything the hb800 is the location for text based mode 0 - screen 0. it is in binary so you would just reference it to load where you need it.

Comment: Im running Al=13 INT 10 320x200 pixels 80x40 characters